# Searching Images in Solr 3.3.0

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I am working with Solr 3.3.0 version and I need to index and search Images. I m able to index the image files but it fails to retrieve them as search results.
Can anyone of you help me out with this.

My data-config.xml is :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="bin"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="f" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" recursive="true" 
rootEntity="false" 
 dataSource="null"  baseDir="C:/Files" 
fileName=".*\.(DOC)|(PDF)|(XML)|(xml)|(JPEG)|(jpg)|(ZIP)|(zip)|(pdf)|(doc)" onError="skip">
            <entity name="tika-test" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" dataSource="bin" onError="skip"> 
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/> 
                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/> 
                <field column="text" name="text"/> 
                <field column="id" name="id"/>
                <field column="Keywords" name="keywords" meta="true"/> 
</entity> 
 <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
 <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="links"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

This works fine for types other than images, I am not able to get images in search result

Comment: Can you please add details about your setup ? What descriptors are you using to index them, and what query are you using to retrieve them?

Comment: "I am not able to get images in search result" Does it mean that your images are not indexed (meaning they are not returned, even by the MatchAllDocsQuery, `{!lucene}*:*`), or that Tika fails at extracting meta data from your images (in that case documents will be present, but only with the `file` and `fileAbsolutePath` fields, if supplied at indexing time?

Comment: Images are indexed but when I try to search them using some meta info like author or even with content, they simply do not appear in results, I am not sure whether images are searched like other rich documents on the basis of content or is there any other specific way of searching images?

Comment: Query this "id:my-image-id" for each image and report what is being returned. If it were successfully indexed, the metadata would have been returned.

Answer (score -1):

Ans) you have to search in solr admin page using the query in URL after indexed..
when ever you images are indexed it will display in **Overview** tab of solr admin ..
suppose it is not displaying the documents and time in **solr web pag**e the image is not indexed still iam searching the same .....**